# Groupby sum by Inspector_ID, and Day in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below. Which is the distance travelled by two inspector in different day.

```
Inspector_ID      Timestamp                  Distance
    1              2018-07-24 7:31:00          0
    1              2018-07-24 7:31:01          2.3
    1              2018-07-24 7:33:01          2.8
    1              2018-07-25 7:32:04          0
    1              2018-07-25 7:33:06          3.6
    2              2018-07-20 8:35:08          0
    2              2018-07-20 8:36:10          5.6
    2              2018-07-20 8:37:09          2.1
    2              2018-07-27 8:38:00          0
    2              2018-07-27 8:39:00          3
    2              2018-07-27 8:40:00          2.6
```

From the above, I would like to prepare below dataframe

Expected output

```
Inspector_ID   Day_of_the_month   Total_distance   No.of_entries_in that_day  week_of_the_month
1              24                 5.1              3                          4
1              25                 3.6              2                          4
2              20                 7.7              3                          3
2              27                 5.6              3                          4
```

Comment: do you have the data for just 1 month? else there should be a month column too?

Comment: @anky_91 No, I have the data of other months as well, At this time, let us consider as one year data . Assume that the data is for just 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd

    from datetime import datetime as dt
    df={"Inspector_ID":[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]     ,"Timestamp" :["2018-07-24 7:31:00" ,"2018-07-24 7:31:01" ,"2018-07-24 7:33:01" ,"2018-07-25 7:32:04" ,"2018-07-25 7:33:06","2018-07-20 7:31:00" ,"2018-07-20 8:36:10" ,"2018-07-20 8:37:09","2018-07-27 8:38:00" ,"2018-07-27 8:39:00","2018-07-27 8:38:00"],"Distance":[0,2.3,2.8,0,3.6,0,5.6,2.1,0,3,2.6]}

    df["Day"]=[]
    df["week_of_month"]=[]

    for entry in df["Timestamp"]:  
        df["Day"].append(dt.strptime(entry,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').day)
        df["week_of_month"].append((dt.strptime(entry,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').day - 1) // 7 + 1)

    df=pd.DataFrame(df)

    result=df.groupby(['Inspector_ID','Day','week_of_month'])['Distance'].agg({"totdist":"sum","NoEntries":"count"})
    print(result)
```

Comment: create dataframe to dictionary first to apply logic